# Join Two Tables in ViewModel with Lambda Expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, lambda, viewmodel, html.dropdownlistfor

I want to bind a dropdownlist by combaining data from two tables in ViewModel. Could you please clarify me on how can I do this? For example I want to show 4 field from 2 tables  in one row like that:

**MeetingName** / **Name of MeetingCityIdA** / **Name of MeetingCityIdB** / **MeetingDate**

Here are the entities I used:

**Meeting:**

```
public int MeetingID { get; set; }
public string MeetingName { get; set; }
public DateTime MeetingDate { get; set; }
public int? MeetingCityIdA { get; set; }
public int? MeetingCityIdB { get; set; }
public int? MeetingCityIdC { get; set; }
```

**City:**

```
public int CityID { get; set; }
public string CityName { get; set; }
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public Applicant Applicant { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Applicant> Applicants { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

**Model:**

Comment: you should show us your EF mapping

Comment: @Kirill Bestemyanov: Sorry, I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated and Working Answer of @Kirill Bestemyanov:**

```
var list = repository.Meetings
    .GroupJoin(repository.Cities, m => m.MeetingCityIdA, c => c.CityID, (m, c) => new {m, cA = c.DefaultIfEmpty()})
    .SelectMany(z => z.cA.Select(cA => new { m = z.m, cA }))
    .GroupJoin(repository.Cities, m => m.m.MeetingCityIdB, c => c.CityID, (m, c) => new {m.m, m.cA, cB = c.DefaultIfEmpty()})
    .SelectMany(w => w.cB.Select(cB => new { m = w.m, cA= w.cA, cB }))
    .GroupJoin(repository.Cities, m => m.m.MeetingCityIdC, c => c.CityID, (m, c) => new {m.m, m.cA, m.cB, cC = c.DefaultIfEmpty()})
    .SelectMany(t => t.cC.Select(cC => new { m = t.m, cA= t.cA, cB = t.cB, cC }))
    .Select(
        m =>
            new
            {
                m.m.MeetingName,
                NameofMeetingCityIdA = m.cA!=null?m.cA.CityName:null,
                NameofMeetingCityIdB = m.cB!=null?m.cB.CityName:null,
                NameofMeetingCityIdC = m.cC!=null?m.cC.CityName:null,
                m.m.MeetingDate
            });
```

Comment: Interesting answer for your controller, but what about the view?

Answer (score 1):

You can use next linq query:

```
var list = Meetings.GroupJoin(Cities, m => m.MeetingCityIdA, c => c.CityID, (m, c) => new {m, cA = c.DefaultIfEmpty()})
                .SelectMany(z => z.cA.Select(cA => new { m = z.m, cA })
                .GroupJoin(Cities, m => m.m.MeetingCityIdB, c => c.CityID, (m, c) => new {m.m, m.cA, cB = c.DefaultIfEmpty()})
                .SelectMany(z => z.cB.Select(cB => new { m = z.m, cA= z.cA, cB })
                .GroupJoin(Cities, m => m.m.MeetingCityIdC, c => c.CityID, (m, c) => new {m.m, m.cA, m.cB, cC = c.DefaultIfEmpty()})
                .SelectMany(z => z.cC.Select(cC => new { m = z.m, cA= z.cA, cB = z.cB, cC })
                .Select(
                    m =>
                        new
                        {
                            m.m.MeetingName,
                            NameofMeetingCityIdA = m.cA!=null?m.cA.CityName:null,
                            NameofMeetingCityIdB = m.cB!=null?m.cB.CityName:null,
                            NameofMeetingCityIdC = m.cC!=null?m.cC.CityName:null,
                            m.m.MeetingDate
                        });
```

It joins meetings with Cities on MeetingCityIdA, then joins result to Cities on MeetingCityIdB, then select what you want.

But it will be right if you will use navigation properties for entities instead of using Join statement from linq.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do you meant that for populating Dropdownlist we should use a way like on that page? http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx

If so, I think I cannot show three city on the same Dropdownlist line. Am I wrong?

Comment: I don't know what do you want.  In my last comment, I meant that you could set your meeting to get navigation properites to MeetingCityA, MeetingCityB and MeetingCityC out of the box without explicit join in linq query.

Comment: Ok, thanks for reply. Actually I had to use this approach due to some exceptional issue (setting Dropdownlist attribute, etc.) Your code works for MeetingCityIdA and MeetingCityIdB. But, I could not add another meeting like MeetingCityIdC. Could you please update it for 3 City? BR.

Comment: Sorry, but I really tried to lots of combinations try to solve the problem before asking you (I do not know so much about Lambda). The last time showed all three cities only for one Student record that has three city id. The other records that has one or two city id cannot be shown. Maybe a little revision make the query works. Thanks you very muchy for your help. I voted up.

Comment: You are rock!.. Just correcting some little notation mistakes on ".SelectMany" and ".GroupJoin" lines of your perfect answer, I solved my problem. Should anyone else need such a kind of approach, I posted updated code of your answer below. Thank you so much for your help. BR.